# Predict the missing pixel value by CNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, image-processing

The data is images which resize to 256*256.

And for per 8x8 area, we remove 4 pixels from the 8x8 block.

Then iter this process to whole image.

So the task is how to use per block pixels value(60 pixels value) to predict removed 4 pixels value.

Use deep learning, especially CNN.

Please give me some advice.

Comment: my advice is to explain what you want to achieve rephrasing what you said, because I can barely understand what you might be saying...

Comment: Because some image in the floder is not the same size @AlbertoSinigaglia